# how to replace document.write with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I want to replace the document.write with innerHTML. but it won’t create the links when I try it. I don’t know if there is an issue of how I am building the path variable so it won’t print out the links right. Right now it won’t print out any links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script>

    var path = "";
    var href = document.location.href;
    var s = href.split("/");
    for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
        path+="<a class='crumb'  href=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+" </a>";
    }
    i=s.length-1;
    path+="<a class='crumb'  href=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+" </a>";
    var url =  path;
    //document.getElementById(".breadcrumb").innerHTML = url;
    document.write(url);

</script>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap-fileinput/4.2.7/css/fileinput.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootswatch/3.3.5+4/yeti/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/app/css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/app/css/style.css">
<script src="/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap-fileinput/4.2.7/js/fileinput.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap-fileinput/4.2.7/js/fileinput_locale_ja.js"></script>
<script src="/static/app/js/app.js"></script>

<style>

.breadcrumb
{
  witdh : 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.crumb
{
 display: inline-block;
 float : left;
 font: 16px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;   
 color: white;
 background-color: #4E95B6;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.crumb: hover
{
 color: red;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

{{>partials/browser-compatibility}}
<div class = "breadcrumb"> </div>
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this cannot work `document.getElementById('.breadcrumb')`

Comment: where is your script tag located in html? show the html

Comment: why is your `script` tag outside the `head` tag?

Comment: I have been moving it around it was nested at first but I will turn it into a external one soon

Comment: have any of the answers provided worked? where this script tag will be placed eventually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try `document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumb')[0].innerHTML = url;`

Comment: just put the <script> code at the end of your page then it will work

Comment: and yes do not forget to use  document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumb')[0].innerHTML = url;

Comment: after the </html> tag or the </body> tag

Comment: I placed it after the </html> and it works good thank you. I tried after the </body> it didn't work there. I appreciate it.

Comment: well you can keep it exactly before </body> tag. the reason you are not getting links is your script is looking for breadcrumb div at the start of your page but the div is not yet loaded so once you keep your javascript code after div element it will parse the div tag and add links into div. another this you can do is you can use ready function that will load your script once dom is ready.

Answer (score 2):

use document.ready to ensure have loaded the dom;

you have wrongly used the getElementById;

```html
<div id ="breadcrumb"> </div>
<script>

    var path = "";
    var href = document.location.href;
    var s = href.split("/");
    for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
        path+="<a class='crumb'  href=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+" </a>";
    }
    i=s.length-1;
    path+="<a class='crumb'  href=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+" </a>";
    var url =  path;
    document.getElementById('breadcrumb').innerHTML = url;
    //document.write(url);
  </script>
```